# Set GridView first or specific row to be readonly

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, row, commandfield

Making specific columns in gridview to be read-only is quite straight forward.
But I just need to make first or a chosen row to be read-only. Is it possible to achieve this without affecting other editable rows.

Here's my current code. (sample)

```
   <Columns>                
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" HeaderText="Edit" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Col1" ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Col2" ReadOnly="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Col3" ReadOnly="false" />
```

In the row perspective. First column is always read-only and other two rows are editable.
I don't want an edit button to appear in the first row. I want the first row to be entirely read-only. How to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

If above is tough to achieve, then make then I am keen to know how first row in datatable can be added to footer row of gridview (assuming commandField will not add an edit button to footer...)

Answer (score 0):

To make the first row non editable, you can use `RowDataBound` event of the GridView and hide the **Edit** button

First convert your `CommandField` to a `TemplateField` and Hide the **Edit** Button in `RowDataBound` event,

Try something like

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
        {
            e.Row.FindControl("EditLinkButtonName").Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you by anychance had seen one of my earlier posts (question) there's a conflict between RowDataBound and RowDataUpdating events... So I am unable to use what you are suggesting for now at least...

Comment: [As of today's status... `FindControl` is just not finding any control in my aspx page... no textboxes, no dropdownlists etc... When I say *any control*, I am referring to those controls added via `templatefields`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24771214/1389394)